# Can't get Div to show past certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive been working on this for awhile and running on my MAMP server  I can't get the infobar to come down only when the page surpasses 10 pixels from the top.

```
<div class="infobar">

</div>
```

That is what my div looks like and I have my libraries imported like so.

```
<!-- Librarys -->
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And last but not least, the script.js.

```
$(function() {
var banner = $(".infobar");
var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (bodyHeight <= $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() - 10) {
        banner.fadeIn();
    } else {
        banner.hide();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: jquery should def come before script.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including the jQuery library itself, to make work jQuery UI also, you also need to include jQuery.js like `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script><!--include this after jquery library-->
```